# Why did this bottle crumple?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

[image: Two soda bottles, one crumpled]

These two empty 2-liter soda bottles were left forgotten in the back of a closet for three years. When they went in, they were both in good shape. They were both resting on top of something, with nothing even close to being on top of them, and they were not touched or disturbed in any way until I rediscovered them and threw them out (after taking this picture). The only difference is that the one on the right was sealed with its cap on, while the one on the left was open.

Clearly the bottle on the right crumpled because it was sealed, but how? Why did being sealed cause this effect?

I estimate that the bottle's volume decreased by at least 1/4, possibly a bit over 1/3. It started around room temperature (70 F, or 294 Kelvin), and I calculate by the ideal gas law that a 1/4 decrease in volume would correspond to an end temperature of 294 * 3/4 = 220.5 Kelvin, or about -63 F, far below freezing. I do not know the exact end temperature, but it was comfortably warm, almost certainly above 50 F and likely above 60 F, giving a difference less than 1/10 of what would be required for temperature alone to account for this. If temperature is the answer, then what am I missing in my reasoning?

Comment: Is it cold where you are? If so it's likely that the air inside cooled down and had lower pressure than the surrounding atmosphere

Comment: @Triatticus By a big enough margin, in a climate controlled apartment, to cause this magnitude of collapse? That seems unlikely to me, and why wouldn't it reverse itself when the air warmed up again?

Comment: It would depend on the temperature of the air inside when it was closed vs the temperature you found it at, we don't know the initial state of the bottle but it can easily be that much if it was closed on a nice hot day. You'd have to warm it without uncapping it to see if it expanded...say hold it over some steam or place it in some warm water from the faucet

Comment: @Triatticus I have seen this effect before, over shorter time spans, when I was living somewhere with much more effective climate control constraining the temperature to a narrow range. I'm pretty confident that temperature is not the answer, all that seems needed is a sealed cap and time.

Comment: @Douglas: Triatticus is of course right. Try and replicate phenomenon with a fresh, empty bottle. Fill it with hot air, then cap it and observe. Do the same with an identical bottle but don't cap that one. You'll see temperature/contraction of air when cooled is the simple but correct explanation here.

Comment: @Gert I estimate that the volume of the crumpled bottle was decreased by at least 1/4, possibly a bit over 1/3. I calculate with the ideal gas law that even the low end of a 1/4 decrease would require a temperature change from room temperature at the start to drastically below-freezing at the end. Even if it only shrank by 1/8, that's *still* ending well below freezing. The actual difference between start and end temperatures here is an *order of magnitude* smaller.

Comment: @Douglas: could you include these calcs into your question, please?

Comment: @Gert Added, with more numbers.

Comment: I see what could be some liquid at the bottom of the bottle on the right. Could it be as simple as bacteria inside the bottle respiring and thus using up the air inside?

Comment: @Remellion That's the dried remains of the soda that used to be in the bottle, the tiny bit that wouldn't come out when I poured the last serving. I didn't rinse it well, if at all, before it went into the closet. Would bacterial respiration consume air without replacing it, or with at least a net reduction in number of gaseous molecules?

Comment: Here's a link to describe what is (apparently) known in the industry as [paneling](https://www.oberk.com/packaging-crash-course/plastic-bottle-paneling-5-causes-and-the-cures).  It does not appear that one single issue is the cause.

Comment: Of the causes mentioned in the link @StephenG posted, only 1 and 2 could be at work here.

Comment: Humans stink at estimating volume. Such crumpling may easily be much less than 1/3 or 1/4th. (A small pressure difference from changing altitude (10000 -> 5000 feet) causes pretty similar looking crumpling of cheap plastic water bottles. Temperature fluctuation and barometric pressure changes (weather) do more than you think.

Comment: @JonCuster Even 1/10th would still put it at needing a below freezing temperature for that alone to account for it, and that seems an *absurdly* low estimate of the crumpling to me.

Comment: If it was very hot and there was a small amount of soda remaining in the bottle at the end, the air space would have been saturated with water vapor when the lid went on.  When the bottle cooled, most of this water vapor would have condensed, creating a partial vacuum (in addition to the decrease in pressure of the air in the bottle).  This is how vacuum is created in the canning process.

Comment: This is a rather curious "experiment". Did you open the crumpled bottle before throwing it out? If so, what happened then?
I'm wondering if the explanation has something to do with elastic/plastic instabilities. An hypothesis: (i) the bottle is sealed at a given temperature; (ii) the temperature inside decreases slightly, reducing the gas pressure with it; (iii) the pressure difference (even if small) causes the bottle to undergo a large deformation due to a mechanical instability; (iv, tentative) this shape change may have become permanent if the deformation was plastic.